# How to generate a M random binary arrays efficiently in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, random, binary

I want to evaluate a binary function at M different locations. The binary functions is of dimension `D` so the function space to evaluate it is exponential `2^D` (i.e. its inputs are all `[0,1]^D` "strings"). I want its evaluation at `M` unique/different points that are evenly/randomly distributed in the input space. I know how to generate all permutations if I wanted (essentially just tack a 0 or 1 to all previous permutations that have already been evaluated. (Pseudo)code in the appendix). However, thats exponential and I only need a fraction `M` points, not all `2^D`. Is there a quick way to do it? I thought of generating the binary arrays randomly and then if there was a collision to try another value until it was unique. As in:

```
while i < n:
    b_D = randomly_generate_bit_array_length(D) # simply selects each bit randomly with 1/2 prob of choosing 0 or 1.
    if not b_n in HashTable[b_D]:
        HashTable[b_D] = b_D
        i++
```

however, according to the answer I got [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/70926/what-is-the-expected-run-time-of-an-algorithm-that-randomly-generates-n-unique-s/70927#70927) that algorithm seems exponential. Is there a better way to do this where the runtime of my algorithm is only `M` instead of something that depends exponentially on D?

Notice that its not an acceptable answer to try to generate all permutations until we have `M` points because I need the permutations to be randomly distributed among the binary arrays. i.e. if we start from `[0,0,...,0]` then generate `[1,0,...,0]` until we have `M` is not what I want because most of my arrays will end with 0's and I want to get a unbiased distribution of them.

---

To generate all permutations:

```
def _generate_input_data_full(D):
    '''
    full means generate all 2^D.
    '''
    D = D-1
    prev_all_permutations = [ [-1], [1] ]
    current_all_permutations = prev_all_permutations
    for k in range(D):
        current_all_permutations = []
        for prev_perm in prev_all_permutations:
            #print('prev_perm: ', prev_perm)
            for b in [-1,1]:
                new_perm = prev_perm + [b]
                current_all_permutations.append(new_perm)
        prev_all_permutations = current_all_permutations
```

Comment: You'd better tell us your D and M.

Comment: @StefanPochmann why does that matter? They are variables. Initially will be `D=8`,`M=60,000` but I might increase it to `D=256` and `M=120,000`.

Comment: It matters a lot. Your `D=8`, `M=60,000` doesn't even work (you can't find 60000 different points when there are only 256). And with `D=256` and `M=120,000` you're practically guaranteed to not have any collisions so it's O(MD). It only degenerates to being really bad if you're somewhat close to exhausting the space.

Comment: yea. I guess thats right XD, D and M matter. But I guess since D lead to an exponential function `2^D` I tend to forget that small `D` actually lead reasonable numbers (was thinking to much about the rate of growth).

Comment: Another demonstration that D and M matter, or rather that their relationship matters, is in [the `random.sample` source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/random.py#L322). It picks one of two different algorithms, depending on how many elements are wanted and on how large the population is.

Comment: @StefanPochmann just noticed I can't actually hash array :/ so that pseudo-code doesn't even work...

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "array". If you build tuples, those can be hashed. Or use ints (with D bits).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, if you use something like your `D=256` and `M=120,000` then your generate-random-and-filter-collisions is practically O(MD) because *you won't have any collisions at all*.

You pretty much only have a chance at getting collisions if you want a huge number of arrays. As you might know from the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), you need about sqrt(|space|) elements for a 50% chance to have any collision. So with D=256, you'd need to ask for about M = 2<sup>128</sup> = 340282366920938463463374607431768211456 arrays. Just for a 50% chance to have *any* collision.

Relevant news: Just a few days ago [the first public SHA-1 collision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHAttered_-_First_public_collision) was published. That's only 160 bits, and many very smart people have spent a lot of time and computer power to **intentionally** find one collision. You really don't have any practical chance to accidentally create collisions with 256 random bits.

Comment: "You really don't have any practical chance to accidentally create collisions with 256 random bits."  - To the extent that the bits are random, he doesn't get any choice about whether there's a collision or not. :-)

Comment: @AustinHastings Not sure what you're saying. Is there something wrong with what I said?

Comment: do I really have to code myself the generate all binary arrays? It seems that this functionality must be implemented somewhere!

Comment: @CharlieParker What do you mean *"do I really have to..."*? Did someone say that? Anyway, there's the `random` module, there's `os.urandom`, and NumPy also offers random data functionality. I think those are the best options.